# Why is a document being created when I submit a search

Tags: xpages

I'm building a search feature to add to one of my Notes apps.  It's very simple at the moment.  Got a search xpage and a search results xpage.  Oddly, when I submit the search, the correct search results comes up but an empty document is created in the database.

On the submit button, I set it to 'no update' (thinking that might cause this).  Didn't make a difference.

The 'on click' event simply opens the search results xpage.  I'm tossing up some session scoped variables for the search, then there's just a view on the search results page with the filtered list of docs.  Just not sure where the doc creation is coming from.

thanks
clem

Answer (score 0):

opps!  Looks like I had added a document data source to the search xpage.  After removing that, no new doc was created.

Clem

Answer (score 0):

A button of type "Submit" will submit the form and therefore save all datasources on the page. I would recommend avoiding that button type. If you want to specifically save, you can call `datasourceName.save()` or use the simple action.